# Unable to automate calender using selenium in a generic way

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to automate makemytrip travel website using selenium python

```
#Click to select departure date 
departure_Day=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,value='//* 
[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/label')
departure_Day.click()


Departure_Day_Selector=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,value='//div[@class="DayPicker- 
wrapper"]//div[@class="DayPicker-Body"]//div[@class="DayPicker-Day"]').
for date in Departure_Day_Selector:
       if date.get_attribute("aria-label") == "Sat Aug 20 2022":
         date.click()
         time.sleep(3)
         break
```

I dont know why code is not working , I am trying to get selenium to iterate  through calendar dates and select the date which we will give as an input
[Here is HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oano6.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: We can't judge the correctness of your XPath without seeing the HTML which it is operating on.

Comment: i  added the html code